# How to host daemon process that aperiodically updates firebase database?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database, cron, google-cloud-functions

I have so far been very impressed with the firebase platform for hosting a client-side single page app and for data storage.  However, I have one component that I don't know where to host...

I want to have a background process that aperiodically updates the database.  The nature of when an update is needed is based on an external source and, although the general timeframe of when updates are available is known, the exact timing is not.  My thinking was to have a background task running that has some smarts to determine when an update is needed, and then trigger an update at that time.

I don't know where I would host something like this.  I considered running it in a loop in a firebase function, but due to pricing model being based on time, that would get very expensive, and functions are not suited for daemon-type processes.  The actual "database update" would be suitable for a function, but not the triggering logic.  Also, I have seen [functions-cron](https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron) which does offload the triggering logic, but since my updates are not truly periodic, it doesn't seem exactly appropriate.  I haven't looked too much into AppEngine and how that relates to the firebase platform...so basically my question:

**What are the options for "reasonably-priced" hosting an always-running background task?**

Answer (score 2):

Google App Engine - Standard is something you want to look at more.  It is reasonably priced since what you are doing will likely fit into GAE-Std's free daily quota.  In GAE-Std, you create a scheduled cron job: GAE will call you task as if it was an incoming web request.

- See [Firebase doc for integrating with GAE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration#google_app_engine)
- See [GAE doc for cron jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron)

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  The complication I am thinking through is that if I run a cron job, and the ask runs, it may know that I want to dynamically change the cron schedule based on the outcome of the task.  For example, it may make some REST calls and find out that in 1 hour there is an upcoming event that will need to be processed.  Using the cron functionality with a call to a cloud function, is there a way to incorporate this feedback loop?  That is why I was leaning towards a persistent service that is always in a loop.

Comment: There are different types of tasks within GAE-Std.  Cron tasks are invoked according to a regular defined schedule.  Your cron task could be fired frequently to do work or recognize the need for future work.  If future work is needed, such as the event occurring in 1 hour in your example, your cron task can create a push-queue task with a delay of 60 minutes.  GAE-Std will hold that push-queue task and invoke it when the 60 minute delay expires.

Comment: Looping back on this, for now I have decided to go with a dedicated heroku worker dyno that handles both the timing and the firestore updates. We will see how it goes!